# How to access 'this' inside my custom JQuery Widget callback

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, widget

I have added some functionality on top of JCarousel control. Since it is used in many places in our code, so I started on creating a JQuery Widget for it. My problem is that I am unable to get the reference to "this" object inside the callback method of JCarousel control. Please find below sample code for reference.

```
(function ($, undefined) {
$.widget('custom.MyCarousel', {
   options: {
        noOfVisibleItems: 2
        },
   _init: function () { this.BindCarosuel(); },
   BindCarosuel: function () {
   jQuery(this.element).jcarousel({
        size: this.options.noOfVisibleItems.length,
        itemLoadCallback: { this.mycarousel_itemLoadCallback }

        });
   },
   MyWidgetCustomMethod: function (index) {
   },
   mycarousel_itemLoadCallback: function (carousel, state) {
        // How to get access to options object (noOfVisibleItems) 
        // and methods like MyWidgetCustomMethod ?
   }
   }
)
} (jQuery));
```

My problem is inside the method mycarousel_itemLoadCallback - as mentioned in the code above, how to get access to 'this' widget instance? I tried using $.custom.MyCarousel.prototype object but this returns same options data for different widget instances.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you mind fixing the indenting in this question? The way it is right now really is difficult to follow.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the solution to my question: Use $.proxy. Thanks everyone for the help. So the line modified is:

```
itemLoadCallback: { $.proxy(Self.mycarousel_itemLoadCallback, this) }
```

Then in the callback method, this will start referring to the widget instance.

Comment: So `Self` just has `this` assigned to it, before the jcarousel call?

Comment: This is a community site, you can ask, but you don't contribute ??

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use the `me` 'hack'. By assigning `this` to a variable `me` in a more global, yet private, scope, it means you can access the object in your callback. Try something like so:

```
(function ($, undefined)
{
    $.widget('custom.MyCarousel',
    {
        me: this,

        options: {
            noOfVisibleItems: 2
        },

        _init: function () { this.BindCarosuel(); },

        BindCarosuel: function ()
        {
            jQuery(this.element).jcarousel({
                size: this.options.noOfVisibleItems.length,
                itemLoadCallback: { this.mycarousel_itemLoadCallback }

            });
        },

        MyWidgetCustomMethod: function (index) {

        },

        mycarousel_itemLoadCallback: function (carousel, state) {
            // How to get access to options object (noOfVisibleItems) 
            // and methods like MyWidgetCustomMethod ?

            alert(me.options.noOfVisibileItems);
        }
    })
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: I tried this approach, but code is giving error: 'me' is undefined.

Comment: So you must have missed `me: this,` on top

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
$(this)[0]
or
this[0]
```

I'm not sure if it will work with this plugin, but as a rule of thumb - when you have a jquery instance within a callback, and you would like to access underlying object, then you can use array operator to access it as I have shown you above.

Comment: Both of the above options are giving error: $(this)[0].options is undefined, and this[0] is undefined.

Comment: what do `console.log(this)` and `console.log($(this))` show in developers console?

Comment: this has type 'DispHTMLWindow2' and so is of $(this)[0]. Guess both refer to object that raised the callback. But I want the widget instance.

Answer (score -1):

I think following solution works

```
jQuery(this.element).jcarousel({
    size: this.options.noOfVisibleItems.length,
    itemLoadCallback: function(){ return this.mycarousel_itemLoadCallback() }

    });
```